# Steam: OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems

Tags: steam, opengl

I have the fgxrl driver(gfx: Radeon HD7950, 3GB), yet steam provides me this error every time on startup after I installed it.

What is the fix? Do I need to purge both steam and fxgrl, then install fxgrl, THEN steam, or what is the sequence?

Output of spci -k | grep VGA -A2

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti PRO [Radeon HD 7950/8950 OEM / R9 280]
    Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Device 3221
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add output of `lspci -k | grep VGA -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti PRO [Radeon HD 7950/8950 OEM / R9 280]
 Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Device 3221
 Kernel driver in use: radeon

Comment: Why do not [edit] your question and post it there? Just click the word [edit] in my comment, if you can't find how to do it. And your fglrx driver is not installed.

Comment: Sorry! I'm new. I edited it in :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proprietary AMD driver is not installed. You can install it by running

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

in terminal.

If the opensource `radeon` driver works better for you, then use it and ignore that error message.

Comment: I tried using that method before, it resulted in terrible fps in Dota 2 with the fglrx driver. Should I install it and then fiddle with the Dota 2 settings? Or am I just doomed with an AMD gpu?

Comment: If you are happy with opensource driver, than use it and ignore that steam message.

Comment: I'm not happy with either as they provide me with bad fps :-( but  guess i'll benchmark both and see..

Comment: How bad is fps? What do you mean?

Comment: If I run Dota 2 on WIndows 7, I'm having 120 fps stable. On Ubuntu, with both standard and fxgrl drivers, i run max of 60(vsync off I guess) but it drops to 20-30 easily which is terrible